# Retrieving a List<T> from another List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Not too sure I have the title correct but I'll explain.  I have a couple of tables that have relationships between them:
[image: Diagram]

As you can see, Issues can have many `IssueActivities` and Issues can also have `LinkedIssues`.  A `LinkedIssue` is one or more `Issues` that are tied to another `Issue`.  What I'm trying to do is given an `IssueID`, I want to pull back all `LinkedIssues` AND the `IssueActivities` for each.  I'll be using this to display in a DevExpress grid using master/detail.

Here is what the .edmx looks like:
[image: EF Diagram]

**Note** -- The Navigation Properties for `Issue` are `IssueActivities`, `IssueCategory`, and `LinkedIssues`

I am fairly new to using linq with EF so I'm not sure how to approach this.  I know I can get a list of `LinkedIssues` by using

```
UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

var childIssues = (from li in unitOfWork.Context.LinkedIssues
                   where li.IssueId == issueId
                   select li).ToList();
return childIssues;
```

but I'm not sure if it's correct or how to get the `IssueActivities` for each and display them in a grid.

FK relationship between `Issue` and `IssueActivities`
[image]

Comment: IssueActivities has also an `IssueID` (not fk thought), not sure if that is intended or may be a DB design prob... but with your actual schema you could query `IssueActivities` directly by issue ID. Again, that is is just based on your current schema...

Comment: @DavidEspino - That's odd b/c in SQL Server I show it as an FK....see pic in post.